# Do PVC saddle tees meet code in Illinois?

Tags: shower

Can a saddle tee legally be used to tie shower drain into 4 inch main drain in the state of Illinois?  All plumbing is PVC.

Comment: Generally speaking they're prohibited inside buildings. You'd use a pair of shielded couplings and standard sanitary tee. I'm not familiar with Illinois and any deviation from common code, though.